# How to keep :hover selector functional after loading pdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pdf

So i have an anchor element that loads a pdf.  After loading the pdf however, the :hover styling is stuck until I click somewhere else on the screen.  At this point it goes back to normal.  There is no js for it and here is the css:

```
.my-btn {
    color: #3568c4;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #3568c4;
}

.my-btn:hover {
    background-color: #3568c4;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: the browser :active or :visited states are kicking in, override those if you wish

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the browser defaults are getting in your way try resetting them or using your defined classes to set them

> a:hover MUST come after a:link and a:visited in the CSS definition in
>   order to be effective!
>
> a:active MUST come after a:hover in the CSS definition in order to be
>   effective!
>
> Pseudo-class names are not case-sensitive.

```css
.my-btn,
.my-btn:visited {
  color: #3568c4;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: #3568c4;
}

.my-btn:hover {
  background-color: #3568c4;
  color: white;
}

.my-btn:active {
  color: #3568c4;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: #3568c4;
}
```

```html
<p>Note: a:hover MUST come after a:link and a:visited in the CSS definition in order to be effective! </p>
<p>a:active MUST come after a:hover in the CSS definition in order to be effective! </p>
<p>Pseudo-class names are not case-sensitive.</p>
<button class="my-btn">Test</button>
```

Comment: I have the selectors in this order, and added the :visited where you suggested but this is still not working.  I have pdfs set to open in acrobat instead of in the browser, would this have anything to do with it?

Comment: if your browser is losing "focus" it no longer has control of the display until as you said you click on it again then it "goes to normal"

Comment: you could add a class in the click event that forces it change style before Acrobat gains conrol